# How to troubleshoot elements that might be adding PTS latency

Tags: gstreamer

I haven't the faintest idea why, but it seems like a bin that contains some queues and an audiomixer element is adding latency to the video outout.

The basic structure is:

```
webrtcbin -> video -> compositor -> etc
          -> audio -> audiomixer -> etc
```

When the audio segment is not present, video latency is about 200 ms. When it is present, it jumps to 400 ms and continues to climb. You can see this in the graph below.

I've been mauling over https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/audio/gstaudioaggregator.html?gi-language=c#GstAudioAggregator and https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/base/gstaggregator.html?gi-language=c#GstAggregator to see if a parameter or parameters should be set for live sources. \

My general understanding here is that its very likely an audio element is adding 'latency' by having a higher max latency value that what is in the pipeline before it is slotted in. The max latency of each sink becomes the overall latency of the pipeline.

I tried to enable higher level debugging to see if there are any latency events that might explain this level of latency, but I dont see any.

Any ideas would be great!

Glass to Glass video latency is below:

[image]